# Bash alias to delete merged git branches (on windows)

Tags: bash, git, cmder

Trying to make an alias in [Cmder](https://cmder.net/) on windows in order to erase my already merged branchs.

I'm stuck with this :

```
alias deletebranch=for /f %%i in ('git branch --merged=$1') do git branch -d %%i
```

The ouput error is :

> do was unexpected at this time

I saw on other questions that when used in a script we need 2 `%` char... What about aliases ? It's like a command right ? So only 1 `%`

But even if I'm using `%` nor `%%` it doesn't work

I've also tried single and doble quotes.

And btw, `for /f %i in ('git branch --merged=develop') do git branch -d %i` is working if executed right away

Comment: Wait, are you asking about Bash or are you asking about CMD? `for /f` isn't a Bash thing at all, and vice versa `alias` doesn't exist in CMD.

Comment: Well ... Alias exist on Cmder... And I admit I'm a bit lost when executing command in Cmder if it's CMD, bash or shell or whatever ( that's maybe why i'm having trouble with syntax all the time ... )

Comment: You should clarify, where exactly you define an alias, and what shell are you using. Turn on [StatusBar](https://conemu.github.io/en/StatusBar.html), it was created for you.

Comment: So I'm running this command on a CMD.exe and `alias` do exist on it ! (Maybe only with the help of Cmder...) But seems like it refers to `DOSKEY` and that's maybe where is my problem ! Is it possible to have a DOSKEY "storing" such a command ? ( `for /f in...` )